# Methods with anonymous and dynamic type throwing error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ienumerable

The following code loops through `resultSet` and populates list a of `SomeType`.
The `resultSet` itself is an anonymous type with two properties

```
var resultSet = SomeCollection.Select(x => new {
    FirstProp = x,
    SomeMembers = SomeLinkCollection.Where(l => l.SomeId == x.SomeId)
                                    .Select(l => AnotherCollection[l.Id])
});

var result = new List<SomeType>();
foreach (var currentGroup in resultSet) {
    result.Add(new SomeType {
        Prop1 = currentGroup.Item.Id,
        Prop2 = currentGroup.Item.Name,
        Prop3 = currentGroup.SomeMembers.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    });
}
```

To remove setting up new `Sometype` instances I created a mapper class/interface using dynamic type to split the responsibility and use dependency injecton:

```
public class SomeMapper : ISomeMapper {
    public List<SomeType> Map(dynamic resultSet) {
        return resultSet.Select(new SomeType {
            Prop1 = currentGroup.Item.Id,
            Prop2 = currentGroup.Item.Name,
            Prop3 = ((IEnumerable<AnotherType>)resultSet.SomeMembers)
                                                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        });
    }
}
```

So the code above becomes:

```
return resultSet.Select(SomeMapper.Map);
```

Error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I tried few tricks with explicit cast to `SomeType` but it fails at run-time

```
return (List<SomeType>)groupSet.Select(statusGroupMapper.Map);
```

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectListIterator`2[AnotherType,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeType]]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeType]'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a list of the result.

Simply add `.ToList()` after your expression:

```
public class SomeMapper : ISomeMapper {
    public List<SomeType> Map(dynamic resultSet) {
        return resultSet.Select(new SomeType {
            Prop1 = currentGroup.Item.Id,
            Prop2 = currentGroup.Item.Name,
            Prop3 = ((IEnumerable<AnotherType>)resultSet.SomeMembers).OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

`.Select(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`, so this is exactly the same type of problem you would have with this method:

```
public string Name()
{
    return 10; // int
}
```

You also have a problem when you call it, don't do this:

```
return (List<SomeType>)groupSet.Select(statusGroupMapper.Map);
```

just do this:

```
return statusGroupMapper.Map(groupSet);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried using .ToList() but the same error still persists
Unable to cast object of type
'WhereSelectListIterator2[AnotherType,System.Collections.Generic.List1[SomeType]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeType]'.

Comment: You're still casting, remove the cast.

Comment: removing cast gives me compile time error

Error 61 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeType>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeType>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You need to call `.ToList()`, as pointed out in the answer. Can't you simply copy my code and see if that works instead of modifying your own?

Comment: I did call .ToList() also i tried pasting your answer but without explicit casting the compile time error (as detailed above) still persists.

Comment: OK, I see why now, you're also munging up the result when calling it. The result is already a list (when it successfully comes out of the method), you don't need a cast or a `Select` here.